# No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model when trying to use another model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am very new to django and programming. I am seeing the below error when trying to run

`No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`

below is my model definition

```
class Group(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group_description = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        self.save()
        return reverse('group-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class GroupPost1(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group1 = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        self.save()
        return reverse('group-post-detail', kwargs={'group_pk': self.group1.id, 'group_post_pk': self.pk})
```

I have get_absolute_url def in my model. Why am I seeing this error?. any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hi can anyone help me with this. thank you in advance

Comment: what action are you trying to do exactly? seems like you have defined a url on both models.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this helpes, but i don't think its necessary to type `self.save()` when you define the `get_absolute_url` method. If you use built-in class based views for example `django.views.generic.CreateView` this will automatically take care of the saving.